# Add day to a date in Vega-Lite

Tags: date, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to add a day to my dates which look like "2020-11-20" for November, 20, 2020. However I am encountering difficulty doing that - do I need to use the offset function? The reason I am doing this is that Vega-Lite is automatically offsetting my dates back 1 day through its GMT conversion and I cannot get it to stop. Please help!

Here is an [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKFVzMaEAFldEOACdTSTAohJZEfidM1VikJjgAPPam26AyjQAXnBoAIwADAC+kUoAJnDQTjiY7PLofjBsppgABAAqZgj5NAhwwrIhSgDuNLH0+iqymEg0Faau8BpYDbotba6xlig+IMRIggwJaADaoKYMsgD6g+76AEzhG-wR-GsAHK4ppYs4Zuyx+oJIEJiLmFVlpIsIujAQri+ydFlwsYuNEAYpVM73Q+wiADYAOyuOCkJr-K4QCDOGhQSypfQvbIUMhwE4MUywa6VECtZ5IUwAazgtwBQLMoJAoQihxK+KQZDIpj4KTkWNeIBicwWy0sITBm3C-AAnLsDkojvjTk42Bd0EjbvdHvjPvR3kpPt8eX96cCmeDwtDYfC6UiUep0Xy0iAeeNFglmqslOTkNTaf85IDzfoIQBWNZs46c7m8zHoPUwIUKEVLFYSkAbLZ7eVR5VnNWXa5ah6CJ6Jg0gI2YH6moMMkHrPaQmFKOFwBFQe2op3xqtZTC4-E80gg0m+yk0un1kPoBVudmLGM8ijOgVNJPC12i9PrKXbaX7PMnAvqkCau6l8uvSvV2uBuwNi3Nq2tkDtzvdx0Y-kJgdDxYeXUWRbCgcclj9KcH2DRk9whY9lzjX9+w3ZNUzFVZJS2HYj0VRcVXOIsbkvHVnhvD45GNX5oKfJsWxtDs7WuB00R-F1sUHTl8XgQQ2CgVwJ39adH1nZkZQQrkVzY9d6i3eY03FPdsMPeclRPVUzwvbUy11cjDUomsTRo0TLWtNtbURZie2kv8cS4xY8TacYBIgycAzNWD0AAZlwhdo0kpD2MFOSd0UrDpRZbZxLw44CMLDVi0AhYKK+QzqI8xswRfMz3wsrsrO-NdbM4vFFh4viXIpITjM8kBor8jkAtXPtBgATzQ7cFMwzN90i0J6rUuLNMS+SUqousRNq0y3w-JjkWsorXTgd1PUUn1XOqjKmQjSMYsa2NmuQtqOvkjCMyzCLQii48hqI25Rv01L7y2ujXwYz8CtYxaOIAxyzGc9aqqgl6wRlMMJIOmyQGOkKuvO3qrv6m7TzupL5Ee8aasyzNspmvKvy+vsfvskdGXAoH3JnKaBsXRDDpdGGU06s6lMu669vUwiEuIh6UMxkGcfo8zGMs+bCqJ-97JwQliRMSrIMpybsb2VTaaaqHGfQ3dwu2RGadilHufu5KMbSiaYOx6b3rmlje2Q4nSqA1pQPJhXhItplQj2N81LpjWkHa2GWZ1nYvPCZGNNR7Trw3W8DOeqnLdx63RdtqGHeHdsx3ltz3do9AfbVyHvuCpnTu1nrlP4MOI6589Euj3TY7Gs2sefIXcpF-KxcJ5C3UED0bjWskNuBxOmQhHLffVkvUKDiuLoPavw4526jZInSyOb02E6V9u3uFj6e7toK7NK8r+MBt22-0UJwY5v3Z9ksvQu6xfQ5XhrOfi+viMbrf9Qt13h7V6OVZqpwWhLM+mdgIuxzptcet9mwQykk-TcL84asyXjXVehtf4llIhWIBRkBZW0PjbSB9tJalT+hYQQ8Cx5730D5fW+1UESznhg4OlcIrShwV-Ne+CN4x0ATvEhiCsod3Ad3NOJdoEEiJDAEkDDFYgILvfL+j8OHPy1mFHhS81isO-sNP+V4m6iL5q3UhydyEQPFlQ+R0tFHKKvrnG+c5dqaJnto9Bui369UPEYwRWkzEALeMQ9KEjBYH07kfWRUCSrcTKBVVxCCmHoCMVoqhnC-HwyroY2uP8QmEL0pY4B+dolgPxp9E+Ap5G0IBiPCmedRI+S8igwKMlfHMwXgE3YQS8HFM3kQsRkT0mVLxl3AmtT0D90Hl6V2biBYQmQQ-bx2SdE9L0e-QJhSTEEOGaUu84jxlkNiRQ+xp9EmASznLVJjC1HMlCB0+mXSTqvzybw-peyo6hJGWUk5jyznSOmenahMDnayDAiolptV+oaOnsXHx7zMEh0PIXA2kd17-3+ccsZQKbHnLsb3K5AEnGy0WWkx5KsXlgpyVs-x+SMX5ixUInFRz46AoqcC6px8wX1I7P9eh9zVHcqhAiou7CNndPLtsvpaxmXGN+SU7eAL8XcsJSCmp-Lrmk2ziK2FytaVoJRdwnZuxFXBIbn8jlT0uUmU1by+JDjrkXxhe45kYhjXIvnnKplPzsU2tVXi82GqpFOsoS6OZq1vRNOvgLMMUJPGIqlUFelsrGVfIVQGtlQaLEho9TyqZ2q5G6rgLAqFlKHkVNCBCZNkrOl-nTR8rBOFVaYrrkMkR4TRmhodeG4tfLS1kplkou5callRJZJ-FNjaUKbIzZ8gx7aWWdutSq-NnL1X9piVqodCSAJ6vHYJatokV1LnWWmhdLa0W5lwayrt5ie1qr7VNR1g7nWkvsg04VE6qUVJ8uerJV6ZU3v0W2nNj6wlxztdut9A64mRrqa65Jl8-2nrhZky9bzfWZuXZB9dhzg1btfUnBDFySXIcPeWyF0KDWFqtN66Vpren5PPVa0xG7n0FuseR4lMylorSHrGk9orRLhnrf5JFzHcNLsiuECVHaf6JjuGwFmvbC3vsQ5cqj37BV0PdaQmU7S1nSYZgHFjfq2YKZzSpms6mX2ab4zIpDxVqOjmPaPMTtUvKKbYXOzWDK5NXRs-euudm1O7g07x3dEadNualqOlx6HvPYwhFhsz+hAuLtbSFvzSqm30FUw5njUSi3aco7M5aA8Y1VtS9tcIXrTOpqyxZ2TuX+ChYEXgiLJWSNOdix+1z-Z5FuvowLDLLX0DZbA+-PLtnXjFai45mLVShvxZG2WitdGUuGs9l5SbAW2tcNY1my1gzCPdpg-zMrWmKMCejcJure39CJsk-515hXQOovA+igjnGiObtg6R-ea2KsCYzjc7bz2PW1vexezLX3LN4Zwudh9l2n3Xasbd5zoLh0k1uTDgWQHsNI-a7e7NYWikY+gxEkHoDJng51QBMbu3YdNa8Yj+d32zXyrR2ugHV26cDbB-d5niXnGeeaR6mlzW52JmR3Jv7VP9nCMx8L1bjOxf45ofpxpomXtgnFUxkDivW18JnfhC7gv1fRZx4NpnOuIUgUrYZqdqzOdTe52b29-DBrW4OULu3py7v8fF6VclY6idRON3Lz73vye-eXv9wPtuVv29F2Hp3NyPPR-GYq4DOGTtWewZbpTqv2XEeByLrXWeD32VZwb2H+XC9k+Lyji3Ke1e0+DwS3HJa+yPYWW78Zk8C+k4T+3pXyeVfKsB9x-rmuU4uY25Dn9I-HksJN0X3JHXGOz-QDgEc7AGAQEWA8OAVINcZ9ryvyrm33Nkw3zWw78eZs-bm51+CB+QBH7hCfs-C-K-XvMNB3bXevc+VDZ-EybfabY7XfEOELb-brVlP-YgAA8-OAS-a-EPfvfdF1ajaHaAuFMQV-f2QOKfPfZA-3VA4-NgU-TA7AkAndTPO-B7areZYeJvBNCEMvD7cgn3cDJAnNNAjAoAnAvvMAuvAgiXClYgtLEzT3I7CghAoQr-EQughg8Q5g+DKQtg8PfEdfcbW7eHVvaGeAoLc3b5H-KDXFRfG-ZfPHCA53OBYw8ZeFWAyfVQ81ApGwmnOw6vJfWxfQ7PIwtnAWNpTwhXRPHwgZdHG3HvdPXAvQpwvuDg2reQieD3WdePaIyginOIgXVPRI0rZI1g1Ir9R2QnTI2+Z5OPOla9D-eVQo6nBIgIm7Mo2-Co3TSA3iNDbgqJMgk1GI5orvSvIHDoyQ8ogfGQiPJLKXeNKJPYUwifPI7whGTrfLQRUQ+gwArA4ApIqYromYqNdIp7Go9AMMRrTw9-XnbCebH-HYrQ-YiQ0A6Y-AyopJPoi4uqG4iwnLRAzYjQ--XYxgg40oo4xwk4nolw13Nwx5UIA7P4lQywwErrGguuJ4vYpgw4t444j4mEnPJ-eEgDFvCfW407XWIEx4zQ7E8E+wzoqEgkhLOYyXPPR5dLZEwQz-dEq3WgkE54nEiEvEpkz9QksIgY05YzLkkY+49Qn-XrZbYUlg-EsUlk2EnbSUhE0gmU-ItQ-fFA8LRbezJUhkyE4I7o9Uok-VcIqdIYlqf42bDYg0jE5TY0yLYeZU3Q94tUh-BvKAkkmA+oxaCkkveTagvko0jcJbT0s0kUi06EqrITYfQM2qMMXg3U9YuUl0yMt06Mk02MwIhwhM5kv01kuQ1MhQzM1E-UiM8vLpGM2NL0sjFIxMsswwvXX9LUjVFYrnUM-xfqJecIOow01o4o9o7HRkks308YAeAtSQeg0wCoVqSsbs0SFkaU4Mn1PUjYQc+TEc10ivPNBfIsqcolEIvsWcreTGBcwkZc1crzQ3ZkNYREqI0udYvctYTrA83Mo8rjLHcpFU0U4bK8+cxc+8n40IF8vghHL3NYmsxeYc78sY48gC+1b01UkCwQOc-rW8pcuAFcyC6Ct85tJorYTYZCvwto21SY+M88y0kAUC3C8Cgih86XAWDcxQnIhonnSk8ILySi0cv8+fNCuDFsn0rCnC6vPCiCysz2RrEnLneCgE-RRrQSw8ufIPXEoC6cyS681uGS1ioi1kLcmTHc-cBTdS38zStPZs0HTCjbJi6SliwiuS2+BSkixou46UK0Ky+swNf814nS+itspym8lytixY9w-qLihtXI98hCiyqEPy1dMc7vCcwCjC4Cxy7C-S+8Qy1y209wl82KqTOChKlSxCnMYclCwKnQ8Shy+-MKgyiK4ymCsw5Sp08iuUGqqi8cmiyc80kK0s5q-K1qty9ATizy3isMnyn8-y3NOq7SrK3SnKqS8Ku8oyia58180y03WU6zea1K4SrSuyhnbKpq3KsCzawqtcuFYivanfRK-JGCjjW4HyMUQqs6yRVskaq65im6yKyddwmJbikMx0sirNI6grIRD6tqUS+nH6iStavKoyAqoG-9dc0GuKgQg6gxeHN6xYOGgOBGmvC6gTUatG8aoqx5GUbInG8GlEyq+VUq461GYmr6uM4KvdGc-65ywGyC4c3sr3fs6fNYDnDS9eDm0moI4a3m9alqgW7aum6Gsw0WqwtYLYgPImtYT6mW4suWvS66-C26x82HIW6s5m-JOstmqW3W+GoKlaw2lG422SmmmtbGsq5Q7kvnLvaWx2hq8mqGSm6idGn4lWy2rqrNdjbW-2+q+yoOxaEOv4MO7aiIKCyOyGgxFo1XOO5awO1ay6hWsapW920SCOx6uApmqO0vP2+2kmgOhOwuimvmjak2jGjDbGdO4W72vG0OaGwmvO76iZROy81uxW9uwWjOyu8w6urO-cuuvWxu865u4O8ekuyetOz2-gxmn27Mgm2O+uzm08oanmo2gGzesu2qCupQt-CG7yqk-ixeh2+Ole52ou1G0O6mu6rui2me9WtEiW6yu2pe1+pGxqlu4uqm0un+pkG+sGh0ueh++TLW+I96o+-Ws8s+l2i+t22B9y6e2+3G8y7Mm2mGi8Iermp27Bj+12raq+3+qeBmxBve6zfnNKyhk+uimhyBz+lO7+s2ibemr2u+pByk+TGOtBnW0B-Opu9+3huh029iqdP+oh3evukLHO9mjB5e8B0e5CZOxYVOhhuB4RnelhjRg8Z+husBke1epO9e6By+-Bya1RhBo6e+8RxGAew+mR4e8rcAgxxxr+mBwRlRphkR4hrMtmQhyW2GnR2xgJ6Ql0Qx4xlxuqMx2C3ukhmJ1m8hxKTh2i7muLWh3B+h9J7uzO5BxGIBhaihhJ2Rt+nhteqBkJ5xsJ8ZeB5hjxsRsMxGVBoo6Rl+xpvR+xse1p-h0J5RkG2J7p8zXplHRGMhwehp-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-QNd1QMMGUKEFAPD6D7d-wIICUKC1D9D2jpoAAdTgC6G8BACYCI4uCY7KEI+I-QFI-I8o9cCuGY7o+CDCCiFJY8EnfZAAFVUoXWFg6B9Bu3KRExdxSXoBxgJRQBX2Q3MB+JSW3WzwctFRp2Mx3AEAcAshGkkA-2AOFx8P9AAARcUHITlzz1qWt1z6DzDxD5D8IfjjD+D4LnD6jgjojrIEjsQMjijqj+uSTtjjjsgbodAHj918TtDgT2L5dkTpL3L1LzAAIaTo90LgLuAFjsr+jsINYMLzdpD6DtAfgcMJQSl5ALjsDhAfgMD2IfrwOUlmsIjlIHAXt8z-QJtxiVt9tx129nL2ZFtPaZT9TkYNTrjzTql14ZbBgEztATAeYOAEbugVr9ATz9wbz3z-zoz-QWz+zgzXVxbs8FVtVjV7V2NLr4D9AUDiD57u99AfBzrrIbr-QJQaL+997p9wjphAHpbxpkHoDrjiH6r-QWHj2NVkjIUElrcSCSd6zy4Udhdgr+Ljdndvdk9qFNUbDq9l1qb9AN7x9qcZ92NO79961z9r0GgH9uThT0oNb7wUATbjT5aHbjcPbg71AI7yYXTul4ztDBnywqzt9twRAR75yEbtgMbmgCb1AWYV1l76b5ttt6E+HizlbhqQX1TlT9Abb7T4efb-iaX4707tzi7rznzgOW7wn9AB7hz+hc3qH5n2kVn0kb7rjv7jqJX4H110Hn71wSHxnh9jVjH2iIPptIp2CJHsH9AVHlId3kANP80LH4HHH6IEloAA). If you look at the timeline graph it ends at 2020-11-19, but the final date in my data is 2020-11-20, and I need to make it so 2020-11-20 is the last date on my timeline graph.

Comment: It's not clear from your description what your question is. Can you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of a chart specification that shows the issue you're seeing, and what you would like to be different?

Comment: @jakevdp I edited the above post to include a vega-lite spec to help illustrate what i mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue comes from an unfortunate "feature" of how javascript parses dates. Here is a minimal example of the problem you're seeing ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUkUG8IATAAwUC0AjDbQOwgA0Iy6xcArAL7MHROZSuVr0aADhZtUmeADY+AoiQrU6tAJzT2cuAyXhBqkWKoUdszhJ4BdPiAC2EAE4BrEgCNX0jADsAYwB7MABLPwBzeFAAD2iQADNQjBQwEl1iVigATwAHIQBHNAg-KFCYMsRiB2z4pJS0uCMVLNDHDABVP3KSbIxXRyDSgAtCTJAc-JIglzC-VBAHKCCglDLcvFB61JIx6TL2rp6mvoGhqFHjLLyhIkdcmYW7Hh4gA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2020-11-17", "value": 5},
      {"date": "2020-11-18", "value": 6},
      {"date": "2020-11-19", "value": 7},
      {"date": "2020-11-20", "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {
      "field": "date",
      "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
      "type": "ordinal"
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {
        "field": "date",
        "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
        "type": "temporal"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Each of the days in the chart are off by one compared to the input. So why is this happening?

Well, it turns out that the Vega-Lite's renderer makes use of Javascript's built-in date parsing, and Javascript's date parsing treats inputs differently depending on how they're formatted. In particular, Javascript will parse non-standard timestamps in UTC time, but will parse full ISO-8601 timestamps in local time, a fact you can confirm in your browser's javascript console (I executed this on a computer set to PST):

```javascript
> new Date('2020-11-20')
Thu Nov 19 2020 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

> new Date('2020-11-20T00:00:00')
Fri Nov 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

The Vega-Lite docs recommend using UTC timeUnits and scales to work around this, but I tend to find that approach a bit clunky. Instead, I try to always specify dates in Vega-Lite via full ISO 8601 timestamps.

In your case, the best approach is probably to use a calculate transform to regularize your dates, and proceed from there. Modifying the simplified example above, it might look something like this ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUkUG8IATAAwUC0AjDbQOwgA0Iy6xcArAL7MHROZSuVr0aADhZtUmeADY+AoiQrU6tAJzT2cuAyXhBqkWKoUdszhJ4BdPiCgAnCADssAMwD2TgLZ5QAGNUQLQUYzhHLwARQQAKQjRfADpCDAACAGp0gHIAFXJyOELi8hyASmkIHEi0kDtWXwgnAGsSACNm6QxXQK8wAEtXAHN4UAAPMZAPAYwUMBJdYlYoAE8AByEARzQ3KAGYfcRiB1WpmbmF2uMVgd8MAFVXA5JVjGbfL1coAAs6lY2Qh8g1cqHqKy8XhQ+3WAWms3mJH+jjuj2eUFe7z8X1+yLWmxIRF86x8YLsPB4QA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2020-11-17", "value": 5},
      {"date": "2020-11-18", "value": 6},
      {"date": "2020-11-19", "value": 7},
      {"date": "2020-11-20", "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "toDate(datum.date + 'T00:00:00')", "as": "date"}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {
      "field": "date",
      "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
      "type": "ordinal"
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {
        "field": "date",
        "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
        "type": "temporal"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]